# Order products table by using orderBy() according to a column in users table [laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables in the database  Products and Users

I have this SQL query

```
Product::where('status',5)
   ->where('user_id',120)
   ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
   ->paginate(50)
```

and I have a column in USERS table called valid_rate

all i need is to order those products by valid_rate column in the users table

to  be like that  Product::where('status',5)->orderBy('valid_rate','DESC')->get();

Comment: What is the relation between Product and User models?  How will you order the *product* by the column on the users table - do you want to order the users who are related to that product by the valid rate?

Comment: i want to order the products according to that user by the valid rate column?

Comment: If there is *one* user, and the `valid_rate` is on that user, I don't understand how you can order by the column on the user model.  If the valid rate was on the product or a pivot table (user + valid rate), this could work.  I may not be understanding, I'm sorry.

Comment: the valid_rat is in the users model

Comment: Please show Models relationships.

Answer (score 1):

```
Product::with('user')->where('status',5)
   ->where('user_id',120)
   ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
   ->paginate(50);
```

if you have product relationship with user of eloquent relationship laravel

Answer (score 0):

First join two table on user id.

Your code will be like this

```
//join users table with product  
//replace (products) with product table name
Product::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'products.user_id') 
    ->where('products.status',5)
    ->where('products.user_id',120)
    ->orderBy('users.valid_rate','DESC')
    ->paginate(50)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Product::with('users')->where('status',5)
   ->where('user_id',120)
   ->orderBy('valid_rate','DESC')
   ->paginate(50);
```